# Advice on how to transfer space in a BTRFS setup

Tags: opensuse, lvm, btrfs

I have had problems with my 40GB root partition and want to transfer space from a second 400GB partition. I have BTRFS installed on top of LVM. For some reason, OpenSUSE decided this for me an installation time and I considered it made sense:

```
# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 464.5G  0 disk 
`-sda1            8:1    0 464.5G  0 part 
  |-system-swap 254:0    0     2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  |-system-root 254:1    0    40G  0 lvm  /
  `-system-opt  254:2    0 422.5G  0 lvm  /optLVM
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

# btrfs filesystem show
Label: none  uuid: 681e689d-1ac2-48ac-9fba-f6a6e234e9f5
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 28.40GiB
    devid    1 size 40.00GiB used 35.53GiB path /dev/mapper/system-root

Label: none  uuid: 90b22bed-5924-425d-ac30-03279f970fa0
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 159.43GiB
    devid    1 size 300.00GiB used 299.04GiB path /dev/mapper/system-opt
```

As you see, /dev/mapper/system-opt only has 300GB, so I have 100 GB free there as I did a btrfs resize to free 100 GB.

My problem is that I don't know how to add those 100GB into / directory (/dev/mapper/system-root). I have tried:

```
# btrfs device add /dev/mapper/system-opt /
/dev/mapper/system-opt appears to contain an existing filesystem (btrfs).
Use the -f option to force overwrite.
```

It seems OpenSUSE formats btrfs on top of dm-1 and dm-2 which probably map to LVM volumes.

```
# btrfs device usage /
/dev/dm-1, ID: 1
   Device size:            40.00GiB
   Data,single:            33.00GiB
   Metadata,single:         2.50GiB
   System,single:          32.00MiB
   Unallocated:             4.47GiB
# btrfs device usage /optLVM
/dev/dm-2, ID: 1
   Device size:           422.50GiB
   Data,single:           297.01GiB
   Metadata,single:         8.00MiB
   Metadata,DUP:            2.00GiB
   System,single:           4.00MiB
   System,DUP:             16.00MiB
   Unallocated:           988.00MiB
```

Can I do?

```
 btrfs device add /dev/dm-2 /
```

To make / (root btrfs "partition") get the Unallocated 100GB in the dm-2 partition?

Answer (score 1):

dm-# is device multipath, so basically btrfs partitions are being treated as LUNs.

The resize option works to expand partitions as well as reduce them.

```
 btrfs filesystem resize +100G /
```

You may need to do something similar at the device level first to move the free space to the logical drive that holds the root partition.

btrfs reference at [kernel.org](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/UseCases) seems to show that the command I listed may do the trick.

Comment: I have tried that and just that does not work as / already has all available space already used (40 GB, I get a no enough free space error). / directory is in /dev/dm-1, what i really need is adding the unallocated space in /dev/dm-2 into /, and the executing the command you propose.

Comment: I did not find a command to resize volumes.  Looks like the process you're trying to follow would be better done on a single volume with subvolumes instead of multiple volumes.  I do not understand the configuration of your openSUSE install.

Comment: Yes, I made the wrong decision creating 2 lvm partitions and on top of them, btrfs, but for some reason OpenSUSE suggested this. I now wonder how to solve it. Is there not a way to make the btrfs unallocated blocks of a partition to be used by a different btrfs volume?

Comment: To me this looks like a limitation of btrfs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your BTRFS filesystems are stored on [LVM](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) logical volumes. In LVM, logical volumes are made up of chucks (extents) which come from physical volumes (disk partitions) which are grouped together as a single unit known as a volume group. For example, in your case it looks like the OpenSUSE installer did the following:

1. Created an LVM physical volume on /dev/sda1 (ex. `pvcreate /dev/sda1`)
2. Created an LVM volume group named *system* (ex. `vgcreate system /dev/sda1`)
3. Created the LVM logical volumes *swap*, *root*, and *opt*.

You can confirm this with the commands `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`, and `lvdisplay`.

Your *system* volume group has 464.5G of storage it can divide up into logical volumes. So reallocating 100G from *opt* to *root* is a matter of:

1. Shrinking the /optLVM filesystem (which you've done).
2. Shrinking the *opt* logical volume with `lvreduce`. **Be careful with this**. If you shrink it too much you'll ruin /optLVM
3. Resizing the *root* logical volume with `lvresize` to give it the additional 100G.
4. Resizing the / filesystem to inhabit the additional space.